# Kubernetes client (certificate) exception is thrown when spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config added as a dependency

Tags: java, maven, kubernetes

I encountered the following error when added **spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config** dependency to my pom.xml:

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred. Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input Caused by: java.io.IOException: Empty input
```

To disable k8s, I added in bootstrap.yml following param:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      enabled: false
```

But even after that nothing changed and the error remained.

Where else should I look? What parameter should I add so that if I have this dependency in pom.xml, I disable Kubernetes when running tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That problem could happen due to the installed `kubectl`. The easiest way to avoid this problem - rename `~/.kube` (directory with configs) to some other name like `~/.kube-hide`

```
mv ~/.kube ~/.kube-hide
```

And when you will need to use your `kubectl` rename it back

Answer (score 3):

As stated on the Spring Cloud Kubernetes documentation

> Also note that these properties: spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.enabled and spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.enabled only take effect when set in bootstrap.{properties|yml}

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#kubernetes-ecosystem-awareness

So, to actually disable this property, it has to be set in `bootstrap.{properties|yml}` and not in `application.{properties|yml}`.

Also, you can pass the value as a VM option:

```
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled=false
```

if you want to run the application locally.